# Как построить структуру многопоточного приложения на Java? Как передать данные в другой поток?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Это учебный проект, не могу понять как правильно реализовать.
Есть класс данные. Например: class Data (int a, int b){...}
Есть класс - хранилище: clacc Hran ... , у него есть метод добавить элемент и, например, сохранить на диск.

Вопрос 1: Как мне создать поток, в новом потоке создать элемент хранилище, и остановиться. После создать в основном потоке новый элемент Data, и передать его в поток хранилища (вызвать метод Hran.add(Data) потока хранилища)?
Вопрос 2: Как вызвать из основного потока метод saveToFile() класса хранилища, чтобы сохранение работало в потоке хранилища, а основной поток пошел дальше?

Comment: Давайте по порядку - создать поток не проблема. На счет хранилища надо определиться - что именно вы там будете хранить, как туда класть и извлекать информацию это может быть очередь, стэк, список или set и т.д.

Comment: Что вы понимаете под фразой `и остановиться`?

Comment: А есть сама задача, что нужно реализовать? Или вы это сами абстрактный пример придумали?

Comment: Нечто похожее делал здесь https://github.com/jlk191603/FileReadWriteThreadsExample может поможет разобраться, если этого не достаточно то уточните вопрос

Comment: передавать данные из потока в поток проще и надежнее всего с помощью `ArrayBlockingQueue`.

Comment: Задача - научиться работать с потоками. Прочитал Шилда, там только общие сведения о создании потока, хочу освоить полнее. Приветствуются ссылки или названия книг. Задачу придумал сам. Данные планирую хранить в ArrayList. Под фразой "и остановиться" я имею в виду: В потоке - хранилище будет объект, в котором лежит ArrayList, в котором сохранены экземпляры Дата. Когда поток заканчивает работу, он должен оставаться в памяти и хранить объекты Дата. И на вызовы из других потоков принимать новые или отдавать имеющиеся. Что-то наподобие SQL сервера. Но как отдельный поток.

Comment: лучше добавьте однопоточный пример на Java. Так людям будет понятней.

Comment: Обычно потоки используют для распараллеливания операций, чтоб больше нагрузить железо и сократить время выполнения. Или когда что-то нужно сделать в отложенном режиме, например пользователь нажал кнопку получил быстрый ответ, а за кадром там запустилась операция по сбору отчета. По поводу остановки - поток останавливается после выполнения всех операций - потом вы из него уже ничего не прочитаете. Если вам нужно чтоб он постоянно крутился, делайте в нем бесконечный цикл while(!isInterrupted()){...}, тогда он будет крутится пока вы его не тормознете из другого потока.

Comment: Собственно то о чем вы спрашиваете есть в этом примере https://github.com/jlk191603/FileReadWriteThreadsExample. Там отдельный поток который создает два хранилища, и запускает несколько других потоков которые работают с ним. Дожидается окончания работы других потоков, потом завершается сам